# Transcoding ERROR : jellyfin-ffmpeg/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration, portainer, openmediavault, jellyfin

Here is my problem, I switched from Jellyfin Win10 to Jellyfin via OMV6 Portainers (official images).
I have I7-2600S (VAAPI)

Except that the transcoding doesn't work anymore, in the Jellyfin logs I have the following error message:

```
[h264_vaapi @ 0x557ec1743400] No usable encoding entrypoint found for profile VAProfileH264High (7).
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

In the attachment you will find information after the "vainfo" we have the following error

[screenshot vainfo command here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEAUn.png)

```
libva error: /usr/lib/jellyfin-ffmpeg/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
```

If anyone has a clue, let me know

NOTE : In Windows 10 i have no problem to transcoding in any format